# accessing array elements from other function

Tags: function, matlab

I have written a matlab function ;now as I simulate it the following error occurs

```
h(n) = (str.(n));
```

??? Attempt to
reference field of
non-structure array.;
I could not figure it out . Can any one help ?

function control(varargin)

```
str =  {
    'violet';
    'indigo';
    'blue';
    'green';
    'yellow';
    'orange';
    'red';
    };

N = length(str);
h = zeros(N,1);
for n =1:N
    h(n) = str.(n);
end
```

What is the problem with statement h(n)? I want to store str elements in h(n). I also want to pass values to vibgyor from another function. How do I call it from other function?

Answer (score 1):

Variable str is not a structure, it is an array of strings.
You can convert it as below

```
str =  {
    'violet';
    'indigo';
    'blue';
    'green';
    'yellow';
    'orange';
    'red';
    };

N = length(str);
h = zeros(N,6);

for n =1:N
    X=cell2mat(str(n));

    for m=1:length(X)
        h(n,m) = X(m);
    end;
end

h
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated `str` is not a structure so to reference the nth element you would just remove the dot on this line:

```
 h(n) = str(n);
```

However that would give you this error:

> ??? The following error occurred converting from cell to double: Error
>   using ==> double Conversion to double from cell is not possible.

That is because you initialized `h` to zeros and you are trying to make it a cell array. So you should change to the following:

```
str =  {
    'violet';
    'indigo';
    'blue';
    'green';
    'yellow';
    'orange';
    'red';
    };

N = length(str);
h = cell(N,1);
for n =1:N
    h(n) = str(n);
end
```

However, if all you are doing is assigning `h` to `str` why would you not skip the `for` loop and just do this

```
h = str;
```